# How to Group_By months from this data frame

Tags: r, group-by, sum

[image]

This data frame has two columns, `Date` and `sum_pips`. I've been trying to `group_by` each month and find the total `sum_pips` for each month. For example, all the June's in this data frame equal to a sum of 2700 pips. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on reproducible examples, esp sharing your data using dput()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use the `month()` function from the `lubridate` package, which teases out the months from date-formatted variables as follows:

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2022/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 100),
                 sum_pips = rnbinom(100, mu = 55,  size = 0.75))
```

Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(month(Date)) %>% 
  summarize(sum_all_pips = sum(sum_pips))
```

Output:

```
#   `month(Date)` sum_all_pips
#           <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1             1         1387
# 2             2         1663
# 3             3         1783
# 4             4          803
```

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively a duplicate of [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272), albeit needing to know how to extract the "month" for each row. Assuming your date column is of the appropriate `Date` class (and not strings), then you can likely do something like:

```r
transform(yourdata, mon = format(Date, format = "%b")) |>
  stats:::aggregate.formula(formula = sum_pips ~ mon, FUN = sum)
```

or in dplyr,

```r
library(dplyr)
group_by(yourdata, mon = format(Date, format = "%b")) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(sum_pips))
```